# Flattening arrowhead in TikZ arrow self-loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I want to generate the figure on the right. I am sending the code shown on the left.

can anybody help me?

Thank you!

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=green!50!black,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[state]         (X)                {$X$};


  \Loop[dist=2cm,dir=NO,,labelstyle=above](1)  

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not just provide a snippet but a MWE (minimal working example). It's much easier than having to build the document preamble stuff ourselves and you will more likely get an answer. Besides that: Welcome to TSX

Comment: the arrow cap on the right is called `Bar` on the TikZ documentation (not `stealth`)

Comment: Please fix your code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(I show both arrows on one node). The MWE for above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,quotes}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
       auto,
       > = Stealth,
 every edge/.append style = {draw, semithick, shorten >=1pt},
          bar edge/.style = {semithick, -{Bar[width=3mm,line width=1pt]}},
every state/.append style = {draw=none, fill=green!50!black, text=white}
                    ]
\node (X) [state]  {$X$};
\path[->]       (X) edge [out=120,in=60,distance=15mm,swap,"1" ']   (X);
\path[bar edge] (X) edge [out=-120,in=-60,distance=15mm,swap,"1"]   (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

From code in question can be concluded (regarding used obsolete syntax) that you haven't recent TikZ package (3.0.1). Also is used a command which not exist in `tikz` package.